# Fastest way to create 5,000,000,000 empty files in 5,000 directories in bash

Tags: bash, loops, file, file-io

So I need to create 5,000,000,000 files on a linux drive - empty files. What is the fastest / most efficient way to achieve this?

What I am currently trying:

`for dir in /xfs/*/; do seq 1 1000000 | xargs -n1 -I% bash -c 'touch '$dir/file%' ; done;`

This is "working," albeit very slowly. (creating 1,000,000 files in 5,000 directories).

Is there a better way to accomplish this? (without running in to the *Argument list too long* issue)

TIA

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Bash has no point here, you could have just `xargs -I% touch $dir/file%` with the same result

Comment: though calling a separate copy of `touch` per file (as the `xargs` suggestion above does) is a bad idea here in general when you care about performance at all; going to spend much more time starting new copies of `/bin/touch` than actually creating the files, at least until your write buffer gets full.

Comment: BTW, `xargs -I% bash -c '...%...'` is in general a serious code smell from a security standpoint. Granted, here your values are always numeric -- but if you were iterating over filenames or other freeform content, you'd need to worry about something like `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` being substituted in place of `%`, and thereafter one copy or the other (depending on what kind of quoting context the `%` is in) being run as code.

Comment: ...if you're going to use `xargs bash -c`, leave the `-I%` out; just `xargs bash -c 'for arg; do ..."$arg"...; done' _`, and let xargs put the arguments in `$1`, `$2`, etc. positions, for the `for` loop to subsequently store each in `"$arg"`. But again, for the specific problem at hand here, you don't need xargs _or_ bash at all.

Comment: 5,000,000,000 empty files in 5,000 directories is actually 1,000,000 files per directory. I have doubts about the ability of filesystems to handle this or it is going to have a dramatic performance cost. Getting ride of the files afterward or simply addressing these files is going to be an issue. Also keep in mind EXT4 has a hard limit of 2³² files 4294967296 per partition and this is less than the 5,000,000,000 files you want to create.

Comment: See `df -i` for current inode limits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`touch` is an external program that you are having to start 5,000,000,000 times. You are also running `seq` 5,000 times. Don't run either of them.

```
for dir in /xfs/*/; do
    for ((i=1; i <= 1000000; i++)); do
        : > "$dir/file$i"
    done
done
```

This loop is a single shell command that spawns no additional processes; the `:` command's output redirection is handled by a single system call in the current shell.

Comment: One should also be able to just run `> "$dir/file$i"` with no `:`, but as a built-in, I can't see it _hurting_ this way.

Comment: I'm assuming the IO cost of creating the file dwarfs whatever slight internal speedup might come from the implicit shell command. Though to be honest, I kept `:` for POSIX reasons, but that's irrelevant given I used the C-style for loop :).

Comment: Thank you, this is working much better. I'm newer to this, and I knew I was doing it improperly.  This is working *a lot* faster.

Comment: Maybe it'll go even faster if you parallelize the inner for loops

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with your code is `xargs -n1 -I% bash -c 'touch`. For each file to be created you are executing two processes - first `bash`, then `touch`. Spawning processes takes time and two for a single file is going to be a lot.

The following could be faster, but I suspect the pure bash solution in another answer may be faster anyway. `find` outputs a list of directories inside `/xfs/`. Then `seq` outputs that directory with the filename suffixed with a number. Then the resulting strings are passed to `touch`.

```
find /xfs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d |
xargs -d'\n' -I{} seq -f "{}/file%.0f" 1000000 |
xargs -d'\n' touch
```

If you have GNU `xargs`, you could easily parallelize the execution by adding `-P<num>` to the last `xargs`.

Comment: TIL that BSD `seq` implements the `-f` extension; I'd assumed it to be a GNUism. (Not that "extension" is a meaningful concept for a command that isn't standard-defined at all).

Comment: Personally, I'd probably parallelize by using chepner's answer only for the inner loop, and your `find` for the outer loop. `find /xfs/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec xargs -0 -P 20 bash -c 'for dir in "$@"; do for ((i=1; i <= 1000000; i++)); do >>"$dir/file$i"; done; done' _ {} +` -- tuning that 20 to whatever load the local I/O subsystem will bear.

Answer (score 1):

Split nothing to millions. This is fast because it is one process, that immediately decides what the output is, and just create empty files.

```
for dir in ./*/; do
    split -d -n1000000 /dev/null "$dir/file"
done
```

I noticed similar times for this modification:

```
find . -type d | xargs -I{} split -d -n1000000 /dev/null {}/file
```